# Why is the hardest part of programming is naming things?

Tags: programming-languages, naming-conventions, software-design

I have heard that the hardest part for a programmer is naming variables, classes, objects and methods etc. really? then why do we focus more on algorithms and Data Structure?

Comment: Don't forget that like with any *lapidary* phrases, they emphasize one particular aspect at the expense of the others.  And we all know that complicated things in the world are rarely black/white (good/bad etc). Also note that such statements quite typically have a tint of humor. ;-)

Comment: The only other hard problem is invalidating caches. By which I mean: don't take all this too seriously.

Comment: The way I heard it is, "there are only two hard problems in software development; they are: cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-one errors."  ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well on my opinion any project should have the documentation where you will define a naming convention for the project. 
Beacause if you leave all programmers to name classes, variables, properties, methods etc... by itself. It might lead to difficulty in understand instantly what is purpose of the class, method etc...
Think about this, the name should be as much self describing for person which never saw your code to understood what it intendeed for.

Comment: The quoted phrase isn't really about finding a naming convention. It is about finding the actual terms. The problem is, just like natural language translation can be partially done by computers (weather reports are proof of that), no word in a language nor programming language matches its translation 100%. So if you have a concept in your mind, it likely matches existing words only partially, and you have to find the word that is the least misleading. We haven't yet figured out how to do such fuzzy matching well enough.

Answer (score 3):

**Disclaimer:** The below post was written in 2015, before the current understanding of "AI" as a shorthand for statistically-driven *large language models* had taken hold. I am referring to traditional Turing-style machine intelligence with that phrase here, not the more modern meaning. About computers able to process and generate natural language from actual calculation results and algorithms, not just picking the most likely word to follow like a more advanced cell phone keyboard.

---

Because naming stuff is something that requires you to understand human language and the problem domain of a program, which so far only humans can do. There *is* research going on into solving the naming problem, it is called "artificial intelligence" or "natural language generation", "expert systems" and the like.

It's just that these areas are still so much in their infancy. Computers these days can barely understand what people tell them in natural language, forget actually coming up with sentences and general-purpose answers and solutions of their own. So this research might as well not yet exist as far as programming language researchers are concerned.

What is possible these days is usually too much effort for what it's worth. We could probably look up some algorithms and implement an "algorithmic spell check" for programs based on variable names and bleeding-edge tech like Wolfram Alpha, but who would pay for that if you can just get a pre-made implementation of that algorithm off of Github or from your language's standard library?

Mind you, that is today. Once AI and the more modern equivalents have advanced, I'm sure it'll all be integrated into programming languages.

Comment: I'd be interested in hearing why this was downvoted. Thanks.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the topic. The hardest part for a programmer is to *choose names for their classes and variables*. Has nothing to do with AI *naming* a thing.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the downvote. I understood this as a tooling-related question (it *is* in "programming-languages" after all). I read the question as "We focus so much on tools and libraries that do algorithms and data structures, why don't we build tools that solve the naming problem?".

Comment: http://diehealthy.org/software/naming-things